# Python TypeError when printing traceback of AttributeError using traceback.print_exc()

Tags: python, traceback

A reproducible example:

```
import traceback
X = None
try:
    X.text
except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
    traceback.print_exc(e)
```

This will raise an error at `traceback.print_exc(e)`:

`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'AttributeError' and 'int'`

Any suggestion why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print_exc` doesn't take the exception object as an argument, it uses `sys.exc_info()` to obtain exception information. When you're passing it `e`, it's interpreting it as a positional argument for `limit` which expects a type `int`. I believe if you just remove the argument you'll get the result you're looking for.

[traceback.print_exc documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation : [Python Docs - traceback module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#module-traceback)

The first argument to traceback.print_exc isn't the exception, it is a depth limit of how many deep the traceback goes. You are hitting an exception within the traceback module itselse, since it expects the first argument to be a limit.

Your code needs to be :

```
import traceback
X = None
try:
    X.text
except (TypeError, AttributeError) as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

The exception data is kept as a thread global in `sys.exc_info()` which is what `traceback.print_exc()` uses.

Comment: Yeah, that's it, wasted an hour on this, thank you guys so much.